# Caffe only trains for one label

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

This is really weird. I'm implementing this model:

[image]

Except that I read data from a text file using an ImageData blob, batch_size: 1. There are only two labels and the text file is organized as usual

> ```
> /home/.../pathToFile 0
> ...
> /home/.../pathToFile 1
> ```

Still, Caffe only trains and tests label 0!

I run caffe using the regular tool.

`./build/tools/caffe train --solver=solver.prototxt`

When I open the net in pycaffe I get this message for the first time ever:

`WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR`

and the size of the
`net.blobs['label'].data`
is now 1, when it should be 2!

Not only that but that label seems to be a float rather than an integer.

```
In: net.blobs['label'].data
Out: array([ 0.], dtype=float32)
```

I know that this has worked before, I just can't get my head around what I'm doing wrong or where to begin troubleshoot.

Comment: if your `batch_size` is 1 what do you expect `label` shape to be??

Comment: After I changed the batch_size, label gets the right number of elements. Thank you, Shai! However, net.forward still outputs a vector of length 1.

Comment: it outputs the loss, this is a scalar regardless of input size.

Comment: you can replace SoftmaxWithLoss layer with a simple Softmax layer to get the class probability per input

Comment: Alright! Thank you, Shai!

Comment: If you want to make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll delete this thread now as it is now solved. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output shape of your network depends on the input `batch_size`: if you define `batch_size: 1` than your net processes a **single** example each time, thus it only reads a single `label`. If you change `batch_size` to 2, caffe will read two samples and consequently the shape of `label` will become 2.
One exception to this "shape rule" is the loss output: the loss defines a **scalar** function with respect to which gradients are computed. Thus, the loss output will always be a scalar regardless of the input shape.

Regarding the data type of `label`: Caffe stores all variables in "Blobs" of type `float32`.